# Xbee sending wrong ZDO responses

Tags: xbee, zigbee

I´m playing around with two Xbees, one defined as coordinator, another as router. I want to read information about the network interoperably so i decided to use the ZDO messages.

I send a message like this ((profile ID 0x00 00, cluster ID 0x 00 31) and receive for example the following response from the router:

```
7E 00 2D 91 00 13 A2 00 40 E5 F0 B4 FB CE 00 00 80 31 00 00 01 2C 00 01 00 01 58 CE C1 8D 7A 3F 2D 40 AB F0 E5 40 00 A2 13 00 00 00 04 02 00 FF 33
```

Correct answer cluster ID: 0x 80 31

Focussing on the RF Data i have the following:

```
2C 00 01 00 01 58 CE C1 8D 7A 3F 2D 40 AB F0 E5 40 00 A2 13 00 00 00 04 02 00 FF
```

I now try to decode this hex string and face some problems.

From my point of view, this string should be encoded like defined within the ZigBee Spec from 2012, at Table 2.126 and 2.127

Unfortunately this don´t work for me. If i ignore, that the first byte should be the status and take the first two of them, i can read out NeighborTableEntries, StartIndex, NeighborTabelListCount. But when it comes to the NeighTableList i only can read out the Extended PAN id, the extended address and the network address, the rest of the string does not fit to the standard. Am i doing something wrong here or does the xbee´s don´t stick to the standard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
2C = Sequence Number
00 = Status (Success)
01 = 1 entry (total)
00 = starting at index 0
01 = 1 entry (in packet)
58 CE C1 8D 7A 3F 2D 40 = Extended Pan ID
AB F0 E5 40 00 A2 13 00 = IEEE address
00 00 = NodeId
04 = (Coordinator, RxOnWhenIdle)
02 = (Unknown Permit Join)
00 = (Coordinator)
FF = (LQI)
```

The values after the NodeId are bitmasks, not bytes.